# Docker build extremely slow in a machine running a swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm using my laptop as a single-noded Docker Swarm cluster.

After deploying my cluster, it gets extremely slow to run a *docker build* command. Even if a command is cached (e.g. RUN chmod ...), it takes sometimes minutes to complete.

How can I debug this and understand what's the cause of the slowdown?

**Context**

Number of services in my swarm cluster: **22**

Docker version: **18.04-ce**

Host OS: **Linux 4.15.15**

Host Arch: **x86_64**

Host specs: **i7, 16GB of RAM, SSD/HDD hybrid disk** (docker *images* are stored in the HDD part)

Using VMs or docker-machine: **No**

Comment: Check the system resources. How much CPU is used, how much RAM is used? How much disk traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it turned out to be too much disk I/O.

As I've mentioned above, my laptop's storage is separated into an SSD disk and an HDD disk. The docker images are stored in the HDD disk, but so are the docker **volumes** created (which I initially overlooked).

The cluster that I am running locally contains a PostgreSQL database that receives a lot of writes. Those writes were clogging my HDD disk, so the solution to this specific problem was to mount PostgreSQL's storage in a directory stored in the SDD disk. Find below the debug procedure.

I found this out by using **iostat** like instructed in this [blog post](http://bencane.com/2012/08/06/troubleshooting-high-io-wait-in-linux/):

```
iostat -x 2 5
```

By looking at the output of this command, it became clear that my HDD disk's %utilized param was up to 99%, so it was probably the culprit. Next, I ran **iotop** and dockerd+postgres was at the top of the list.

In conclusion, if your containers are very I/O intensive, they could slow down the whole docker infrastructure to a crawl.